# How to set CCSID for MQQueueManager from code?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have some strange problem. I think I followed documentation correctly but my code doesn't work. I have this very simple hard coded test (NUnit):

```
[TestFixture]
public class MQQueueTests {

    public const string MessageContent = "<test>This is test message</test>";

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var tests = new MQQueueTests();
        tests.PutAndGetMessage();
    }

    [Test]
    public void PutAndGetMessage() {
        var properties = new Hashtable
                             {
                                 {MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "TestServer"},
                                 {MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "Test.Channel"},
                                 {MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1415},
                                 // Is this correct? It looks like it is not 
                                 // enough because adding this line didn't solve 
                                 // the problem.
                                 {MQC.CCSID_PROPERTY, 437}  
                             };

        using (var manager = new MQQueueManager("Test.Queue.Manager", properties)) {
            using (MQQueue queue = manager.AccessQueue("Test.Queue", 
                MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF)) {

                MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
                message.WriteUTF(MessageContent);
                queue.Put(message);

                MQMessage readMessage = new MQMessage();
                queue.Get(readMessage);

                Assert.AreEqual(MessageContent, readMessage.ReadUTF());

                queue.Close();
            }
            manager.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the test application either from console or through Resharper 6 test runner. If I run the application in test runner I always get following exception:

> IBM.WMQ.MQException : MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR (reason code is 2539)

The exception is thrown by `MQQueueManager.Connect` (called by its constructor).

If I check MQ logs I see:

> AMQ9541: CCSID supplied for data conversion not supported.
>
> EXPLANATION: The program ended because, either the source CCSID '437'
>   or the target CCSID '852' is not valid, or is not currently supported.
>
> ACTION: Correct the CCSID that is not valid, or ensure that the
>   requested CCSID can be supported.

If I run the application from the console I got the same error but if I change the code page for console by calling

```
chcp 437
```

My test application works. How can I configure code page from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found a workaround - it can probably solve my problem but I'm not very satisfied with it. I can set up `MQCCSID` environment variable either globally or by calling:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCCSID", "437");
```

That will configure code page. Still I would like to use properties of a new `MQQueueManager` instance to setup code page.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are answers correct. For Windows Forms Project setting the environment variable MQCCSID the same as the ccsid of the Queue Manager that you are trying to connect will be enough.
- the 2nd  solution

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->Control->Nls->CodePage>OEMCP value.

i had a web application(web forms) that only worked with the 2nd solution

Answer (score 0):

change your system locale to English(United States), on windows 7 Regional Settings -> Administrative->Change System locale. also after do that you can check it in regedit value.
regedit->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->Control->Nls->CodePage  check OEMCP value.